# Is there any way to hide part of a div with the new implementations of css3 and html5?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I remember seeing some of these animations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH9WLrcsrx8 and was wondering about being able to recreate some of them using css3 and/or html5. Specifically the animations where (if we're speaking in html) a div would partially appear upwards in a puff of smoke.

In css3 and html5 canvas we're able to do some stunning things: https://freshdesignweb.com/html5-css3-3d-examples-demo/ however I'm wondering if a div could partially and gradually appear upwards in a puff of smoke.

Is this possible using these technologies?

As far as I'm aware we can only manipulate full div's, not partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may alter the height of a div gradually by using CSS animations or transitions to give the illusion that it is gradually appearing upwards. I have created a pure CSS example but it could be done with javascript and/or canvases as well. To save time I have used a grey div as the "puff of smoke", but you may wish to change it to an animated background or something else depending on your needs.

```css
.smoke {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  height: 140px;
  opacity: 0;
  
  /* You will probably want to use a animated gif as the background instead of a gradient */
  background: radial-gradient(circle, darkgrey, white);
  border-radius: 50px;
  
  animation-name: smoke;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

.element-to-appear {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes appear {
    0% {
      height: 0px;
      top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
      height: 100px;
      top: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes smoke {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="element-to-appear">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vero ornatus commune mea et, sale facer graeco ex vim. Ut nonumes mediocritatem est, soluta             instructior no eos. Ad quo quaestio principes. Dolorem dissentiet his ad.
        </div>
        <div class="smoke">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want the div to fade in asymmetrically you can create a mask and slide it like so:

```css
#fade-in {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:300px;
    left: 0px;
}

#mask {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    
    animation-name: mask-anim;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    width:600px;
    left: -600px;
}

#mask, #fade-in {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 200px
}

@keyframes mask-anim {
    0% {
       left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
       left: -600px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="fade-in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu liberavisse interpretaris mel, qui te nonumes suavitate mediocritatem, vel no commodo appellantur. Alii putant audiam te per, ius et rebum porro. Ad voluptatum incorrupte quo, viris denique eum no. Id esse dicant partiendo ius, sed doctus placerat ut. In quo fugit epicuri ponderum, et eos oblique labitur.
</div>
<div id="mask"></div>
```

Comment: But there is no way to partially or gradually appear a div is there? It has to remain in rectangle format. It can't be 20% of side A, whilst side B is at 50% appearance?

Comment: Divs have to remain in rectangle format but there are many tricks for making it look otherwise. (eg. rounded borders until it looks circular.) I have added another animation example at your suggestion.